# Change permalink incrementor into pseudo-subdirectory

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

how I can change permalink from

```
www.mydomain.com/lyrics/title

www.mydomain.com/lyrics/title-2

www.mydomain.com/lyrics/title-3
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/lyrics/1/title

www.mydomain.com/lyrics/2/title

www.mydomain.com/lyrics/3/title
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix with this plugin:

https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

my theme uses custom post type for lyrics

https://muusico.net/